FedCM issue with new attributes on google one tap button without sign in
I am also facing the same issue and "Third-party sign-in" setting is enabled but still when the site is not logged in using one tap I am getting
button:1 getUserInfo() is disabled because the IDP Sign-In Status is signed-out.
/TGNewUI/Search/Home/home?partnerid=13617&siteid=6812#home:1 Not signed in with the identity provider.
client:50 [GSI_LOGGER]:  get() rejects with NetworkError: Error retrieving a token.

Not sure if my fixes will help you, but I ran into similar issues and here's what I did:

For the error regarding token, I fixed it by enabling both third-party sign-in and also third-party cookies.

